# Network devices disabled

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I've been running the Lucid Lynx alpha since first release and only now, after recently putting my computer into suspend then restarting, has the networking failed completely.

Both wireless and ethernet list as disabled with `sudo lshw -C network`. The wireless adapter is an Atheros AR928X. The ethernet is a Realtek RTL8111/8168B.

Any suggestions as to how I might go about fixing this?

Comment: Just looking for the widest spread of answers possible. I've also posted this to the Lucid Lynx development forum.

Comment: Seems like a decent question to me, although if I were Tao, I'd just reinstall Lucid.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an old problem some people were experiencing in Intrepid.

try opening up `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/10NetworkManager` and add this line to the script:

```
sudo /sbin/ifup wlan0
```

So the end result looks like this:

```
case "$1" in
hibernate|suspend)
suspend_nm
;;
thaw|resume)
resume_nm
/sbin/ifup wlan0 
;;
*)
;;
esac
```

Comment: I should clarify: even reboots do not solve the issue. I have lost networking even from a cold start.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by editing a state file -- check out this link

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1419416

(Note: don't delete the file as an earlier poster said -- just edit it like in the later posting.